# Why is Google Ads crashing android app only on release version?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I am building an Android app with Android Studio with Google Ads.
The app seems to work well when I build it locally with test ads, but once I generate a released build, Google Ads throws an error in the middle of the app.

Any insight is appreciated, thank you!

**Stack trace from production app**
[image]

**CountDownActivity.java**

```
public class CountDownActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private AdView mBannedAdView;
   ...
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      mBannerAdview = findViewById(R.id.adView_count_down);
      if (mBannerAdview != null) {
         mBannerAdview.loadAd(adRequest);
      }
   }
}
```

**activity_count_down.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout>
    ...
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/answerImage"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView_question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-<AD-ID-HERE>"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your stack trace is not sufficient. If I can borrow Mike M.'s expression, *Please post the complete stack trace – that whole section of red lines – as text, rather than a screenshot.*

Comment: does it show the actual ad when you run locally?

Comment: @justArandomUser Yes the ads show up locally when it doesn't crash

Comment: @hata I was not able to retrieve the complete stack trace because the production app is not in debug mode. The app does not crash in debug mode.